# Modifying iPhone Camera/Flashlight?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I was wondering if there's anyway to modify how the iPhone takes pictures. Specifically, if you can turn off the dimmer focus flash that shows up before the full flash, so when you take a picture it's just the full flashlight that comes on immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, I think not. From the [apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5):

> Flash Modes
>
> There are three flash modes:
>
> AVCaptureFlashModeOff: The flash will never fire.
>   AVCaptureFlashModeOn: The flash will always fire.
>   AVCaptureFlashModeAuto: The flash will fire dependent on the ambient
>   light conditions. You use hasFlash to determine whether a device has a
>   flash. If that method returns YES, you then use the
>   isFlashModeSupported: method, passing the desired mode to determine
>   whether a device supports a given flash mode, then set the mode using
>   the flashMode property.

And there is no mention of the dimmer flash.

<strike>EDIT: Maybe you can. There are lots of iOS apps that do this</strike>

2nd Edit: After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275929/individual-access-of-camera-led-lights-of-iphone-5s), I have concluded that you cannot do so.

Comment: Do you have any examples of apps that take pictures with no focus flash?

Comment: @javarookie Actually those allowed you to set how bright the torch is only, I am still finding some that allows this

Comment: @javarookie oh and that isn't called the 'dimmer flash', they are caked the dual flash, one white and one yellow, to match the colour of the foreground and background

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I appreciate the help