# How to switch on all iphone 7 LEDs in swift/objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, iphone7plus

Similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275929/individual-access-of-camera-led-lights-of-iphone-5s) but for the iPhone 7.

The iPhone 7 has 2 amber LEDs and 2 white LEDs. When you turn on the torch only 1 of the LEDs turns on. The amber ones turn on intermittently when using the camera in my app (I seem to have no control over this).

So I have 2 questions really:

1. Can I switch on **both white** LEDs on demand in Swift?
2. Is there a way to ensure the amber ones never switch on?

**EDIT**

I have already checked `AVCaptureDevice` and related (whatever is documented), so hoping someone there is someone who has looked under the bonnet and perhaps found another way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no public API method that allows for controlling the exact LED operation on an iPhone. There is only a `flashMode` property available for `AVCaptureDevice`, with three possible values: `on`, `off`, and `auto`.

Comment: Thanks, I should have said I did check the public API's already (as far as I could see relevant). I was hoping there would be another way.